# Is this a legitimate ping test?

Tags: bash, shell-script, debian, raspberry-pi, raspbian

I've been trying to troubleshoot an occasional, but persistent, loss of connectivity and concocted this ping test.  It saves the date of the failure to a file:

```
#!/bin/bash

if ! ping -c 1 google.com >/dev/null 2>&1; then
  echo "$(date): Ping failure" >> /home/pi/Misc/connectivity-test/failure_log.txt
fi
```

And it does catch ping failures.  What I don't know, is whether it covers all types of connectivity failures (due to my inexperience with bash).

1. Is there a better way to do it?
2. Is there a way to also save the actual text of the error?

Comment: One ping might be eaten by the Gods. I always `ping -c 3`.

Comment: If the given host responds to pings and there is no reason for pings to suddenly be eaten for reasons not related to connectivity, ping is a reasonable test for loss of connectivity.  Hosts can be connected and reachable without responding to ICMP echo. A router in between you and the host can eat ICMP echo requests, and such a configuration can suddenly emerge where previously there was a clear path for pings.

Comment: Also, is the idea that Google is never down, so if Google isn't reachable, it's on your end? That's not necessarily correct.   If you want to test whether you have connectivity to the web, it  might be wise to do actual web fetches via a URL, to several major websites (not only Google).